# HahsMap sorting

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

How is this program sorting arrays when Hashmap is not sorted or ordered ?

This program is printing a sorted map from two different sorted arrays

```
class A {
    
    // Function to merge arrays
    static void mergeArrays(int a[], int b[], int n, int m)
    {
    
        // Declaring a map.
        // using map as a inbuilt tool
        // to store elements in sorted order.
        Map<Integer,String> mp = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    
        // Inserting values to a map.
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            mp.put(a[i], "a");
        }
        for(int i = 0;i < m;i++)
        {
            mp.put(b[i], "a");
        }
    
        // Printing keys of the map.
        for (Entry<Integer, String> me : mp.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.print(me.getKey() + " ");
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int a[] = {1,3,5,7}, b[] = {2, 4, 6, 8};
        int size = a.length;
        int size1 = b.length;
        
    
        mergeArrays(a, b, size, size1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maps have *a* order, but that order is nothing to be relied on - any order you may observe is purely coincidental. Therefore the answer to "How is this program sorting arrays [...]" is: it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see a different behavior try changing your initial capacity and load factor.  Something like the following:

```
Map<Integer,String> mp = new HashMap<Integer,String>(2,3.0f);
```

You can read about those [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-int-float-)

Comment: Or try using (say) 7-digit integers with the existing map.  Choose your integers so the digits look reasonably 'random' (not 1000001, 1000002, etc.

Comment: That would work.  But I wanted to show the difference with the same data set.